# Running a Func<T> on a Timer using .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing this as a learning exercise and could do with some help.

The goal is to execute a Func<> on a Timer tick using C#.
The timer is abstracted into another method but the return value of the action needs to be accessed from the main function.

Consider the following code...

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace actionexample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string, string, Task> testFunc = async (f, n) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting Action");
                f += n;
                Console.WriteLine(f);
                await Task.Delay(100);
            };

            SubscribeToConfigAsync<string>("1", "2", testFunc);

            Console.Write("END");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void SubscribeToConfigAsync<T>(string feature, string name, Func<string, string, Task> action)
        {
            var timer = new Timer(5000);
            timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await action(feature, name);
            timer.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to access the values generated by the Func<> inside the Main() after the timers has ticked but am unsure how to do this?

I can't seem to get this to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `Timer`? It has a pretty good example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks, I have the timer working now. I have updated the code. Is there a way to access the return value of the Func from the Main()?

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need the return value in Main?  There's probably a better way of doing it.

Comment: This is a small proof of concept for a larger task.

Comment: Yes, but what would be the point in accessing it in Main?  The method will run every <X> seconds... are you trying to run something every time the timer completes?  In which case you might want to change your action... Or are you waiting for the Timer to complete?  In which case you would want to set a condition that waits for it to halt...

Comment: The Func<> will actually be looking at a repo to get a database value that could change. In reality the contents of the Main will be in another task. The Task will need to react to a change in value from the repo.

Comment: You can raise an event and consume the return value.

Comment: You cannot access any of `testFunc`'s local variables from outside the function itself. You can either have `testFunc` set an outside variable (e.g. a static or member variable that both threads have access to) or you can have `testFunc` perform a callback or raise an event.

Comment: Creating a local variable of `Timer` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what your overall goal is here, but you should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - and it'll make your code vastly simpler. Try this:

```
Func<string, string, string> testFunc = (f, n) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Action");
    return f + n;
};

Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
    .Select(x => testFunc("1", "2"))
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

Console.Write("END");
Console.ReadLine();
```

That does what your current code in your question does.

Let's say I wanted to do something more interesting - let's say I'll create a sequence of numbers from `0` to `4`, produced at `1` second intervals, and I want to concatenate each digit to form a sequence `0`, `01`, `012`, `0123`, `01234` and then stop. Here's how:

```
var last_result =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Take(5)
        .Scan("", (a, x) => a + x.ToString())
        .Do(z => Console.WriteLine(z))
        .Wait();

Console.WriteLine("The last result was: " + last_result);
Console.WriteLine("END");
```

That produces, in the console, this:

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
The last result was: 01234
END
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. How would I unsubscribe from the subscription and stop the timer when I'm done with it?

Comment: @BenCameron if you use `Subscribe` then the return type is `IDisposable` - so you simply call `Dispose()`. In the case of using `.Take(5)` then the timer is automatically stopped after 5 values are produced.

Comment: Thanks. One last point, if you wanted to run testFunc as an async is that possible using Rx?

Comment: @BenCameron - Yes, `Observable.FromAsync(() => testFunc("", ""))`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue`?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var AnswerQueue = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    Func<string, string, Task> testFunc = async (f, n) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Action");
        f += n;
        Console.WriteLine(f);
        AnswerQueue.Enqueue(f);
        await Task.Delay(100);
    };

    SubscribeToConfigAsync<string>("1", "2", testFunc);

    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < 12; ++j1) {
        if (AnswerQueue.TryDequeue(out var ans)) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}: {ans}");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    GlobalTimer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("END");
}

public static System.Timers.Timer GlobalTimer;

static void SubscribeToConfigAsync<T>(string feature, string name, Func<string, string, Task> action) {
    GlobalTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    GlobalTimer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await action(feature, name);
    GlobalTimer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the `Func` in the timer elapsed event, and then after the result get ready, raise an event like `ResultReady` and report the result to all consumers/subscribers.

This means, it's better to create a class like `TaskAgent` which is responsible for accepting the `Func` and running the `Func` in some specific intervals and raise `ResultReady` event.

**Example**

In the following example, to keep things simple, I didn't used async `Func`, but it doesn't change the general concept. The example runs a `Func` using a `TaskAgent` in specific intervals and report the result to `Main` method using event:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Timers;
```

```
namespace Example {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Func<string, string> task = (s) => {
                return new string(s.ToCharArray().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray());
            };
            var taskAgent = new TaskAgent(task, "sample");
            taskAgent.ResultReady += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e);
            taskAgent.Run();
            Console.ReadLine();
            taskAgent.Dispose();
        }
    }
    class TaskAgent : IDisposable {
        Timer timer;
        Func<string, string> task;
        string input;
        public event EventHandler<string> ResultReady;
        public TaskAgent(Func<string, string> task, string input) {
            this.task = task;
            this.input = input;
            this.timer = new Timer() { AutoReset = true, Interval = 1000 };
            this.timer.Enabled = false;
            this.timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
                var result = task(input);
                ResultReady?.Invoke(this, result);
            };
        }
        public void Run() { timer.Start(); }
        public void Dispose() { timer.Dispose(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth to mention, you can have a `Stop` method in the `TaskAgent` class to stop the agent from running task. This way, in the `ResultReady` event handler, depending to the result, you may decide to `Stop` running the agent.

Comment: About the Queue, I'd say using a queue is good idea, but just for queuing the results of execution and just in case if you have a queue processor. If you want to extend my event based solution by adding a queue, you can add the result to a queue and forget about the result and let a queue processor process the queue.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is access to a value that is modified by the `Timer`, you can just make it an instance instead of the containing class

```
public class {
   int Result { get; set; }

   void TimerFunc(a, b) { Result = <some calculation>; }
   Main() {
      StartTimer();
      while(true) { CheckResult(Result); }
   }
}
```

If you are instead wanting to run some logic (such as checking a database) after the other event runs, you need to make both things a part of what's set up for the timer:

```
async void SubscribeToConfigAsync(...){
   await userFunc(...);
   await runDatabaseUpdates(...);
}
```

If instead you want to stop and restart the `Timer` based on some config value changing, you'll want to keep a reference to the `Timer` instance.

```
Main() {
   var oldConfigValues = <empty object>;
   Timer t = null;
   while(true){
      var newConfigValues = GetDbConfigValues();
      if(newConfigValues != oldConfigValues){
         if(t != null){ <stop timer> }
         t = InitializeTimer(newConfigValues);
         oldConfigValues = newConfigValues;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not want to use one more Action as parameter in TimerTick function?

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace actionexample
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<string, string> resultHandler = (a,b,) => {
            //Do something
        }

        Func<string, string, Action<string, string>, Task> testFunc = async (f, n, h) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Action");
            f += n;
            Console.WriteLine(f);
            await Task.Delay(100);
            h(f, n);
        };

        SubscribeToConfigAsync<string>("1", "2", testFunc);

        Console.Write("END");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static void SubscribeToConfigAsync<T>(string feature, string name, Func<string, string, Action<string, string>, Task> action, Action<string, string> handler)
    {
        var timer = new Timer(5000);
        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await action(feature, name, handler);
        timer.Start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try adding it as a delegate. refer below example

```
myTimer.Tick += delegate { System.Console.WriteLine('Inside Delegate'); }
```

Comment: The user is using a different timer.